# Laravel 5* globalization of a eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Guys I am a partial **_create-note-modal.blade.php** and I am trying to share this partial with all the pages and this works perfectly because I included it in the **main.blade.php** template.

> Problem:

This **_create-note.blade.php** partial file get all the **users** from the database using eloquent. This **users** variable need to be share with all the other views because it will get error.

> What I have tried:

I tried to write this in my Controller.php.

```
$users = User::all();
View::share('users', $users);
```

> Question is:

Is that the best way? and what about If I have an entire function that I want to share?

> Notes:

`$users = User::all()` get all the users but actually my project is a CRM for a company that have 25 users on the CRM and won't have more than 100 in the future which is even hard to happen.

Also I return all the users just to view them in `<select>` and `<option>` choose.

Any better solution?

Thanks

Comment: It would be better to accomplish through `service provider`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I wouldn't recommend you to call all user's data without limit. But you have several options. One of these, you have already provided, using `construct` you can call your users variable in the view.

**Option 1:**

```
public function __construct(){
$users = User::all();
View::share('users', $users);
}
```

**Option 2**

In your controller.php you can make a simple function

```
protected function getUsers(){
 return User::all();
}
```

Then you can call `$this->getUsers` in your controller. in this option this query will be worked when you call it.

**Option 3**

Just make a middleware and return it to controller

```
class getUsers {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      $users = User::all();
      $request -> attributes('users' => $users);

       return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In your controller

```
 return Request::get('users');
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to load users in the select dropdown in the all views which belongs to this controller, you can use the first option. But your query should be like this:

```
$users =  Users::pluck('name', 'id');
View::share('users', compact('users'));
```

You can easily load all users in select dropdown:

```
Form::select('users', $users, null);
```

instead of `null` you can put user's id, if you want to mark it as selected.

But, if you want to call your users query in some views, I would recommend to you using second option.

Comment: Would you please tell me what is the best way to get users names just for listing them in dropdown menu or in `<select>` option?

Comment: would you please tell me how I return the user with the ID?

Comment: i have already provided. i put into pluck (name, id). It should return with user's ID

Comment: This is the output when I use `dd($users)` array(12 => "Brad Lewis ", 13 => "Rita Brockhart");

Comment: How I could return the id or now it is the index?

Comment: as you see from dd, it returns all users name and ID. you want to return all user's ID into the selectbox ? or what?

Comment: maybe you missed to send variable to selectbox as compact. I have written it above.

Comment: I have the user id as an index of the element in the array.. now I am trying to return `<option value="{{ $user -> id }}">{{ $user -> name }}</option>`

Comment: Just write in your view: {!! Form::select('name', $users, null) !!}. be sure that this is a blade file.

Comment: take a look to this article:  https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a broad question. I don't think it will be accepted by moderators. To answer it you need to tell a bit more about the app. That piece of code could be  okay within an app that only has a couple of views, in which you always show that form, and you assume there'll be always a few users.
The line:

```
$users = User::all();
```

can be very harmful if you have lots of users stored. So, we can talk a day about sharing something in views, another day about including the same form in all the views, another for always sending a collection of all the users (is it for a selector? autocomplete? just to list them? each one of those situations may have a different solution)

Answer (score 0):

There is a section on this exact scenario described in the official documentation.

See: [Sharing Data With All Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#sharing-data-with-all-views). `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` should already exist in your project structure, it is created by default when the installer runs. However I would be careful, unless you truly need this query on every page, it can easily slow down your site substantially if you are adding a couple of global database queries like this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('key', 'value');
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```